# Make an array with multiple options for music playlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html, audio

I am trying to make a HTML5 playlist using the  tag. I want to store all the songs, their name, description, etc... in an array. I don't know how to use arrays very well though.

What I am thinking right now is this:

```
var songBase = '/songs/'
var playlist = {};
playlist = {
                        'Bleeding Love'             :   'Bleeding_love.mp3',
                        'Don\'t Forget'             :   'Dont_forget.mp3',
                        'Finish'                    :   'Finish.mp3',
                        'In the Rain'               :   'In_the_rain.mp3',
                        'Ready to Fall'             :   'Ready_to_fall.mp3',
                        'Realize'                   :   'Realize.mp3',
                        'Righted All Your Wrongs'   :   'Righted_all_your_wrongs.mp3',
                        'These Walls'               :   'These_walls.mp3'
                    }
```

What I really need to be able to do is have more than 2 options. I also don't even know how to extract any of the data from the array that I already have.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically you are using an object literal ({}) there and not an array ([]).

You can use an array of objects literals for your purposes.

```
var playlist = [
  {
    name: "Bleeding Love",
    file_name: "Bleeding_love.mp3"
  },
  {
    name: "Don't Forget",
    file_name: "Dont_forget.mp3"
  }
]
```

You can then access these like:

```
playlist[1].file_name
```

Or in a loop:

```
for (var i=0; i<playlist.length; i++) {   # i is array index
  for (var k in playlist[i]) {            # k is the key
    console.log(k+': '+playlist[i][k]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Have any idea why this is returning the error `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLAudioElement> has no method 'attr'`                        `var $player = $("audio#music-player")[0];
     
     var i = 0;
     
     var curSong = playlist[i].src;
     
     $(".play-bt").click(function() {
      $player.attr("src",curSong);
     });`

Comment: Not without seeing your page structure.  Make a http://jsfiddle.net and I'll take a look.